# Redirect output of mysqlsh interactive environment

Tags: mysql, stdout

I'm trying to redirect the output of statements made inside the `mysqlsh` interactive environment.

I'm running mysqlsh inside the terminal on OSX and didn't find a proper parameter to achieve the rerouting in the help pages. Rerouting the output via the default "pipe grep > and_run.txt" doesn't work as the mysqlsh environment has it's own set of accepted commands.

My commands are:

```
:$ mysqlsh root@localhost:3306/my_schema
# now the mysqlsh interactive console is open with an active connection to my_schema
mysqlsh> shell.options.set('resultFormat','json')
mysqlsh> session.runSql("SELECT * FROM my_schema.my_table")
# prints the schema as json array - i would like to rerout this output
```

Comment: What language is this supposed to be? `session.runSql(....)` is not syntactically valid bash.

Comment: that is the syntax as proposed by the mysqlsh documentation.

Comment: I don't ask where you got it from, I ask what language you are using: If it is bash, the runSql command is wrong, but the piping to grep is right. If it is a sql shell, the syntax of the runSql command may be correct, I don't think you can pipe the output directly into an external command. At least mysql has most likely no concept of _grep_. Hence, unless you define what language the code is, your question does not make sense.

Comment: I do not know the language and I'm not sure it matters for the context of my question. It's not `bash`, it's a call straight from the documentation that works in and of itself. The result is sent to stdout. I edited the question to reflect that a little better.

Comment: OK, after you edited the code, we see that you are running a "mysqlsh", so the commands should adhere to the language of the mysql-shell. I sadly have no experience with this language, but I googled a bit and could not find any reference of using external programs natively, or piping output into them. May I ask you where you found the information that this is supposed to work? Also, I suggest that you drop the _bash_ tag from your question, because this is confusing in your case.

Comment: I didn't :) I have raw sql-dumps and need json objects (the story is long, sad and complicated). mysqlsh was the first google hit when searching for solutions to my problem and the transformation part couldn't be easier so I'm already happy on that account. I'm neither unfamiliar nor afraid of a shell, so i thought this would be easy... :/

Comment: So, you have a dump in form of SQL statements, and you need to to convert this in into JSON syntax? (The notion of _json **objects**_ does not make much sense to me). Maybe this would be a better starting point for a question. You could post an excerpt of the dump, and a sketch of the JSON code you want to get from it, rather trying out something where even you have no idea how it is supposed to work.

Comment: Closing a question is not decided by a single moderator alone. In your case, I voted for closing it because your posting showed a strange mix of mysqlsh and bash commands and it was not clear in which environment you were running. After editing the question, moderators may decide that it is clear enough to reopen it. However,even after your last edit, I find it confusing: You are tagging at as _mysql_  (which would apply to the MySql or MariaDB command line), but you are talking about MySqlSh, which is a special Shell created by Oracle and contains extensions for the Python language.

Comment: Ok, thank you. It seems my last edit where I cleaned up the tags didn't work. I still think that my question "Redirect output of mysqlsh interactive environment" is valid. Sorry I created confusion by trying to provide some context. I am aware how closing questions works, going into detail here would be a topic for meta... :) I will cease posting here as I don't think that at the moment you're here to help but only point out procedural mistakes inexperienced users make. I am grateful though for the time you put into this and will try to do better next time.

Comment: In contrary, I rather try to get your question into a shape, so that it can attract helpufl answers, because your basic problem (clarifying how to create a pipe within Oracles MySql-Shell) is for sure interesting, now that I understand it. Maybe the answer is as simple as "it can't be done", but for this to know, the right people have to read the question. That's why I suggest that you create a new question with the knowledge gained here. Plus, I would post it on [superuser](https://superuser.com/) instead of SO, because your problem is nor so much about programming, but on how to use mysqlsh.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Thank you! Since this will be deleted anyway and the comments drifted into a meta discussion: The ball is on my side to delete the question, right?

Comment: I am someone who does not throw away things unless I really have to. Likewise, I don't like to delete information unless I have to. If you delete the question, what should happen to the answer you already gave? Obviously someone even upvoted it and got credits for it. I would just leave it like it is right now .... but perhaps some moderator will come up with a different suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

One way to achieve my goal is to not use the "interactive-mode" of `mysqlsh` but open a new connection for each statement.

Not my preferred method as I guess that this initializes a new session for each command, but it works.

```
mysqlsh --uri root@localhost:3306/my_schema --sql --execute "select * from my_table;" --result-format=json/array > my_objects.json
```

I'd really be interested/thankful for a cleaner solution.

Comment: In your "solution", you did not use the mysqlsh environment and are instead inside your bash now. It is not surprising that invoking grep works here, and that's why I said in my earlier comment that your context is important. If you want to do it entirely within the mysqlsh language instead, my _guess_ is that you will have to use the [Python API](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/mysqlsh-api-python/8.0/). In this case, I suggest that you ask a new question, **tag it properly** with the _mysqlsh_ tag, and express explicitly that you are want to solve this within mysqlsh alone.